# IntelliJ running websphere not showing latest changes

Tags: intellij-idea, websphere

I'm running IntelliJ 2019.1 w/ websphere. Ok, I make changes to some local files (.jsp, .xml, etc). I build the artifacts, build the project, deploy said changes and start up websphere. Running my app, I'm not seeing my changes. I've tried deleting the target folder, clearing the browser cache, locating/deleting "old" copies of my EAR, committing my changes to my local repo, tried doing "mvn clean install" in the terminal window. Nothing is working. How can I get my changes to show up when running my app.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html. Try with the latest IDE release, try with the clean app server installation. If it still doesn't work, please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the exact steps to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the exploded ear wasn't getting updated properly. Even though I had specified the exploded ear under "Run > Edit configurations > Before Launch', I still needed to specify the exploded ear under the Deployment tab. Only until I did that, did the exploded ear get updated with the latest changes. This is a confusing of why the artifacts need to be defined in two different places under the Edit Configuration area.